# spring framework xml error in eclipse

Tags: spring

I got the following error:

```
Jul 24, 2015 9:56:05 AMorg.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext prepareRefresh
        INFO: Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@580283d3: startup date [Fri Jul 24 09:56:05 IST 2015]; root of context hierarchy
        Jul 24, 2015 9:56:05 AM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
        INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [Beans.xml]
        Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from class path resource [Beans.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [Beans.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:344)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:304)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:181)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:217)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:188)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:252)
            at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:127)
            at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:93)
            at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:129)
            at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537)
            at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:452)
            at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
            at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
            at com.sj.beans.MainApp.main(MainApp.java:12)
        Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [Beans.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
            at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getInputStream(ClassPathResource.java:172)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:330)
            ... 13 more
```

Comment: share app.properties file.

Comment: It can not find the file `Beans.xml`, share your `applicationContext` path value please

Answer (score 0):

the error info tell us can't found the Beans.xml resource.
check your spring conf see if exist a spell error in the filename?
Or find the file path

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have Beans.xml in resources/META-INF folder. and set the path in web.xml like this

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath:META-INF/Beans.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```